# How can I create a PR in github that only shows changes in a single branch?

Tags: git, github

- I created a branch "A" and made a lot of commits.
- I created a second branch "B" split from branch "A".
- I added commits to both branches.
- I needed some of the new commits from "A" so I merged "A" to "B"
- I added more commits to both.
- I merged "A" to master.
- I made more commits to master.
- I merged master to branch "B".

Now branch "B" is showing all the commits from "A" as if they were part of "B"

Any suggestions on how to get a clean PR/branch with just the changes to branch "B"?

Comment: I suggest cleaning up your branching strategy.  Try to just keep a single level feature branch on top of `master`.

Comment: I completely agree. This is a pretty odd case that certainly could have been avoided. However, no amount fixing things in the future is going to make it any easier for me to fix things on this branch.

Comment: Branch `B` is now a parent of `A`, so all of `A`s commit might show up in the history.  There is really no avoiding this fact other than by going back and rewriting/untangling your history, which probably would not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get a clean PR/branch with just the changes to branch "B"

Fetch from upstream (the original repository) in order to get an updated `upstream/master` (one with PR from `A` merged and accepted)

Reset your own `master` to `upstream/master`.

Create a new branch and rebase B commits onto it:

```
 m--m--m--m       (master, upstream/master)
    \
     a--a--a      (A)
         \
          b--b--b (B)

git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base A B) B

            b'--b'--b' (B)
           /
 m--m--m--m       (master, upstream/master)
    \
     a--a--a      (A)
```

From there, you can force push B, and do your PR from there.

Comment: What specific command do I use to rebase b to b'? I am getting tangled up in the syntax?

Comment: The command should be the one I mention in the answer: you would rebase b to master. The b' are only because the b commits are recreated on top of master, which means their sha1 differ from the original b commits.

Comment: Hmm... that looks like it might work in some cases, but in my case, it ended pulling commits from a lot of other branches.

Comment: @LukeGedeon It depends if the branch graph matches the one I mention, meaning a branch B directly created from A.

Comment: Well, there were several merges from master and the A branch into B along the way and that really made a mess of things. I ended up having to cherry-pick, but I think your answer would work in a less insane case, so I am marking it as correct.